# FlatBuffers - Unable to get the prefixed size of buffer with Boost ASIO

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, flatbuffers

I am using Boost ASIO and FlatBuffers.

Here is how I send message:

```
flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder builder;
std::string str = "ABCDEFG";
auto name = builder.CreateString(str);
auto accountRole = Vibranium::CreateAccountRole_Packet(builder,5,name);
const char *HEADER = "ABVG";
builder.FinishSizePrefixed(accountRole, HEADER);
size_t size = builder.GetSize()
boost::asio::write(s, boost::asio::buffer(buf,size));
std::cout << "Builder GetSize" << size << std::endl;
std::cout << "Prefix Size" << std::to_string(prefixSize) << std::endl;
```

When I send the message I see the following output:

```
Builder GetSize44
Prefix Size40
```

So I believe my prefixed size message is 4 bytes long containing 40 as the actual size of the message following.

`Packet.h`:

```
class Packet {
public:
    Packet()
    {
    }
    static const int header_size_in_bytes = 4;
    uint8_t size[header_size_in_bytes] = {0};
    boost::asio::streambuf body_;
    void PreparePacket(ServerOpcode serverOpcode, std::string message);
};
```

Here is how I try to read the size with Boost Asio:

```
void Vibranium::Client::read_size() {
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    boost::asio::async_read(socket,
    boost::asio::buffer(_packet.size, _packet.header_size_in_bytes),
    [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec,std::size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        if ((boost::asio::error::eof == ec) || (boost::asio::error::connection_reset == ec))
        {
            Disconnect();
        }
        else
        {
            uint8_t size = _packet.size[0];
            std::cout << "Size: > " << size << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Size: > " << _packet.size << std::endl;
        }
    });
}
```

When I try to debug to see what I have inside `size` I see strange output like `40 '('` take a look on the screenshot as well:

[image]

The server gives output of:

```
Size: > (
Size: > (
```

Why?

By my understanding it should be pure `40` as that's the size of the message. Am I wrong? Why it is appearing like that and where is my mistake ?

Comment: `uint8_t` is usually just an alias for `unsigned char` so you're outputting the character representation of the variable.

Comment: Try `static_cast`ing the `uint8_t` value to something like an `unsigned int` so that it gets printed as a numeric value.